# Change font size in Skype messaging

Tags: skype, fonts

Is there a way to change the size of the font in the chat/messaging used in Skype on Ubuntu? I'm using Skype Beta 2.2.0.35, and Ubuntu 11.10.

Currently the font is too small for me, and there doesn't seem to be any obvious was to change this in the Skype options.

Comment: A common complaint.  If you have Compiz, you could make use of the magnifier plugin.  I think it's enabled by default, and mapped to super key + scroll wheel.  Don't remember keyboard keys.  Otherwise, you can try complaining on Skype's message board, like many others have done.  Don't know if that will help, though.

Answer (score 3):

The below link helped me increase my font size for Skype 4.0 on Ubuntu
==> [How to change font size in Skype 4.x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155962/how-to-change-font-size-in-skype-4-x-on-ubuntu-12-04)

### Summarized content of the linked question

> > Install qt4-qtconfig:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

> > run `qtconfig`, choose Gui Style to be Cleanlooks (for example), then save. Restart skype, and the new fonts will be applied. This does not work if the style is Desktop Settings.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Great solution if you use skypeforlinux - you can simply add --force-device-scale-factor attribute in the `skypeforlinux` startup command:

Open skypeforlinux in your favorite editor:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

Change:

```
nohup "$SKYPE_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$SKYPE_LOGS/skype-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```

To:

```
nohup "$SKYPE_PATH" --force-device-scale-factor=1.3 --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$SKYPE_LOGS/skype-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```

That's it.