# How to change font size in Skype 4.x?

Tags: skype, accessibility, fonts

I tried using "qtconfig" but that didn't help. (Even changing the style in Skype, then using Qtconfig won't show any effect.)

Where could I make the fonts larger? (Ubuntu's accessibility settings won't affect it either.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it through qt4-qtconfig. Install it as Eliah Kagan suggested. What he missed, though, is that you have to change the style.

So, when you run qtconfig, choose Gui Style to be Cleanlooks (for example), then save. Restart skype, and the new fonts will be applied. This does not work if the style is Desktop Settings.

Answer (score 20):

Install `qt4-qtconfig`:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

Then run `qtconfig`, make changes, exit, and restart Skype.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. The official Skype client ignores the Qt4 config.

Comment: It worked for me in 4.2 even without a skype restart, font size changed.

Comment: @Shiki In QT4 config, I had to change the GUI Style to Cleanlooks in the Appearance tab. Also had to change the Skype's style to Cleanlooks. Then it all worked.

Comment: @jcarballo: Awesum! Kudos, mate!

Comment: It all worked for me just changing the font size, no need to change GUI style. Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 15):

Open Skype, change the style -> cleanlook. Close it.

Open a terminal and  sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig .

After that open Qt 4 Settings, change fint size, select cleanlook, save and exit.

Open skype again and voila :)

<sup>I tested this in Linux Mint 14 Mate. It should work in Ubuntu too, though.</sup>

Comment: To open the Qt 4 settings run qtconfig-qt4 from terminal.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to install anything. Add the following lines:

```
[Qt]
font="Droid Sans,14,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"
```

To the `.config/Trolltech.conf` file, set the *Clearlooks* theme in Skype and restart.

Comment: Its called _Cleanlooks_

Comment: This seems to work without changing the theme. I used `font="Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0"` to try to match the default font.

Answer (score 1):

In Gnome you can do it in **Control Center**>>**Appearence**>>**Fonts**.