# How do I fix invisible tooltips in Skype?

Tags: skype

I cannot see tooltips in Skype. They are in white text on a white background.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please create a screenshot of the phenomenon and [edit] your question to include a link to it for clarification?

Comment: @Nettlbay-AP It seems the correct answer was posted. Could you please click the check-mark link below then answer-score to mark it as accepted answer? Thank you :)

Comment: @MadMike. Where is the "answer-score"? Star? Sorry, I'm French...

Comment: @NettlebayAP "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." as written here: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the following GTK2 rendering engines can help:

```
sudo apt install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (Ubuntu MATE 14.04.5).
Solved it when I changed Skype style from "Desktop settings" to "Cleanlooks" (Options > General > "Choose style") and ran qtconfig as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155962/how-to-change-font-size-in-skype-4-x).
I only changed the font size in qtconfig, didn't do anything specific for tooltips, but they're displayed properly now.